# MS Word XML Content Controls - custom XML output

Tags: xml, ms-word, data-conversion

I'm trying to devise a way of taking a large number of Word docs/pages and converting the text/content within them to a custom XML output in the simplest way. 
The documents in question are user manuals.

I was originally going down the custom XML route whereby the contents of the Word docs could be tagged manually with custom tags, and I would then use a custom VSTO add-in to output the tags to an XML file in accordance with a schema. However, after looking into that option it seems it not possible due to Word not supporting custom tagging (as such) anymore.

The other option which looks plausible is to use Custom XML Parts. I'm still a little unsure as to whether it's a good fit for what i'm trying to do though. As far as I can see, I could add custom parts to a document like:

'Component' (i.e. water pump)

'Procedure' (i.e remove or install)

'Part Number'

'Spares' (i.e seal, switch)

'Procedural step'

'Graphics'

But the problem is, I don't know how many, let's say, 'Procedural steps' there will be for this particular component. It could be one or 20. If there were 20 then I would need 20  XML elements in the output. Similarly there might be a whole list of 'spares' in one doc, and none in another, same with graphics, so the XML mapping needs to know when to add more elements, or not add elements where not necessary - so the output XML has the correct number of elements.

Does anybody know a good solution to what i'm trying to do?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not really following your thought process well enough, here... If you were doing this manually, what would be the logic? You'd open the document, then...? My gut feeling is that it would probably make sense to get the WordOPenXML in OPC flat-file and either analyze that or run a transform. But a lot depends on how to identify things. If tagging were still possible, how would you have gone about that?

Comment: There could be one Word document with 50 or more procedures in it for various pieces of equipment. The output i need is lots of smaller XML files which conform to an industry standard schema. Ideally i would tag where a new file would start and end, and tag the text into elements which it would map to in the new schema. So yes, whilst it is manual work in terms of manually tagging the data into all its XML elements, it will be quicker than copy and past into many xml files.

Comment: So, your question is primarily about "tagging"... Did you mistype when you wrote "looks plausible to use Custom XMl Parts"? Did you really mean content controls? Yes, that would be a possibility. You could use the Title and/or Tag properties to categorize what you're marking. Content controls can be neseted. Then it would be a matter of extracting the content, which can be done on the WordOpenXML. Probably most efficient to get the document content in the OPC flat file format using Document.Content.WordOpenXML then "parse" that using standard XML tools or possibly an XSLT.